# Can't force https on laravel project

Tags: laravel

I need to use facebook api, and it requires me to have https, so I want to force my laravel project to use it.

With Laravel I use react scafffolding also I run project on Xampp

I already tried

1. setting `'url' => 'https://localhost'` in config/app.php
2. putting `HTTPS=true APP_URL=https://localhost` in .env
3. putting `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https'); if($this->app->environment('production')) {
   \URL::forceScheme('https');
   }` in boot method at appServiceProvider.php

my url seems not to change, it always says localhost:8000

My laravel project is not small, I don't know how mutch code is needed to reprocuce same issue, inform, and I'll provide anything

Comment: The `8000` implies you're using `php artisan serve`, not Xampp. Facebook won't be able to access `localhost` anyways, so your approach isn't going to work either way. Consider something like https://ngrok.com/ for localhost testing with Facebook integrations.

Comment: you're right, I migrated my project to vagrant, thanks